# BadRequest: Failed to execute Skype backend request GetThreadS2SRequest

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Im trying to connect to graph and use the Beta Teams API. I have added a ref to `Microsoft.Graph.Beta` and I have the following code:

```
var orgs = await graphClient.Organization.Request().GetAsync();
var org = orgs.First();
User user = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
Console.WriteLine("Connected as : {0} to {1}", user.DisplayName, org.DisplayName);
var group = await graphClient.Groups["d8947e06-d5b1-435c-9029-7b95820f209f"].Request().GetAsync();
Console.WriteLine("group: {0}", group.DisplayName);
```

This all works and I can get data for the User, Org, and the specified group. All is well until I try to call:

```
var team = await graphClient.Teams[group.Id].Request().GetAsync();
```

**This results in a `BadRequest` and `Failed to execute Skype backend request GetThreadS2SRequest.` which I am at a loss to decipher.**

Here is the scopes I have configured:

```
  "Scopes": [
    "User.Read",
    "Group.ReadWrite.All",
    "ChannelMember.ReadWrite.All",
    "ChannelSettings.ReadWrite.All",
    "Chat.ReadWrite",
    "GroupMember.ReadWrite.All",
    "OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite",
    "Presence.Read.All",
    "Team.ReadBasic.All",
    "TeamMember.ReadWrite.All"
  ],
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I just tried with `Microsoft.Graph` and got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a bug with Microsoft that they are currently fixing. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/7793